# How to take difference between all files in 2 directories and redirect it to some other file

Tags: linux, utilities

I have two directories A and B, which contains common files. I want to take the diffs from all files and collect all diffs in a file.

Answer (score 4):

From `man diff`:

> ```
>   diff - compare files line by line
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   diff [OPTION]... FILES
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   Compare files line by line.
> ```

...

> ```
>    -r  --recursive
>           Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
> ```

So, `diff -r dir1 dir2 > diffs.txt` or just `diff dir1 dir2 > diffs.txt` if you don't need it to be recursive.